# AppleScript X is contained in list of terms

Tags: list, applescript, contains

I thought that simply using the "**or**" operator would allow me to check whether or not a variable, "theMessage" contains "x" or "y". Apparently not.

I tried this:

```
else if theMessage contains {"display", "screen"} then
 --sleep computer's display
  do shell script "pm displaysleepnow"
  set theResponse to "Now sleeping the computer's display"
```

I'll be possibly writing a lot of these, so it'd be great if I could get a subroutine going for *term* in *terms* with operators... e.g.

```
if theMessage contains {....} not {....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a repeat loop, something like this

```
on containsItems from qList against theText
    repeat with anItem in qList
        if theText contains anItem then return true
    end repeat
    return false
end containsItems
```

And use it

```
set theMessage to "ashlfkjhalksjdhfscreenwperoivj"
set queryList to {"display", "screen"}
set doesContain to containsItems from queryList against theMessage
```

Comment: This is why I don't like AppleScript. Doesn't that seem overly complex?

Comment: So every time I want to compare more than one thing e.g. theMessage containing x and y instead of just x, I have to set it as a variable first? Why is it so easy for just one term, but requires all of this for comparing two or more terms?

Comment: Yes, but the handler checks if `theMessage` contains x **or** y. It is easy for one item because you check 1:1. With multiple items you have to check 1:n